# Terraform + Microsoft Azure Stack configuration

Tags: powershell, azure

Can Terraform be configured with using Microsoft Azure Stack? From all tutorials, I have seen that there is a need of using Microsoft Active Directory, which is not available on Stack for basic, only ADFS. I have installed Azure Cli 2.0 as well as Azure PowerShell and I have access to Azure Stack. However, I do not know how to configure the following client_id       = "...", client_secret   = "...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently terraform does not support Azure Stack. Please refer to this [feedback](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7299) on GitHub. Also you could check providers that terraform support, please refer to this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html). You could check similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800486/terraform-config-for-azure-stack/45808336#45808336) on SO.

No, the [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/13) on Github is open, when the issue is closed. Based on my experience, Microsoft stack will be supported by terraform.

Comment: Currently, you could use PowerShell for Azure stack to manage Stack resource, it is different with Azure PowerShell. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-powershell-install).